# ThreeJS CSG with Object3d

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have some issue with threejs. I have a hard object3d which contains sphere, cylinder, circles. These geometric shapes form a complex object. I add this object to scene and and next i add the same but smaller object to the scene.
I can rotate first object, but when a small object goes beyond the borders of a large one, I need to clip it like overflow: hidden in html :-).
I found library "three-csg-ts
" but this library works only with geometry. I tryed use it, It's not correct for me. Because i need rotate this object before i put it on scene.

Maybe somebody can help me?

Comment: There is a working Three CSG library here:
https://github.com/manthrax/THREE-CSGMesh
(supports BufferGeometry).

If you don't need to fill in the sides where you cut the mesh off, and are happy for the sides to be open, Clipping Planes could be a simpler option.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.clippingPlanes

Comment: Note also that you can rotate the Geometry (rather than the object3D) so that be rotation will factored into CSG calculations:
https://threejs.org/docs/?q=buffergeometry#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.rotateX